# How to specify :focus property in JSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, jss

I'm using react-native-web with expo and react-native-paper (material ui)

My problem is textarea on focus outline property in the compiled web version so I need to get rid of this blue borders. Normally I'll do

```
textarea:focus {
    outline:none!important
}
```

With react-native we cannot use css and only jss but how to do it for this property?

```
<TextInput
   label='Email'
   value={this.state.text}
   onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
   style={???} 
/>
```

[working example](https://snack.expo.io/?name=TextInput&description=https%3A%2F%2Fcallstack.github.io%2Freact-native-paper%2Ftext-input.html&code=import%20*%20as%20React%20from%20%27react%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20TextInput%20%7D%20from%20%27react-native-paper%27%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20MyComponent%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20state%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%27%27%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CTextInput%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%27Email%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3D%7Bthis.state.text%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onChangeText%3D%7Btext%20%3D%3E%20this.setState(%7B%20text%20%7D)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&dependencies=react-native-paper)

Comment: Check this - https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.24

Answer (score 2):

You can't do such with inline style of React components. There're 2 ways of achieving this.

Option 1: put your styles inside the component's state and use `onFocus` to manipulate it

Option 2: use a CSS in JS library like https://www.styled-components.com/

Comment: about the first option. can you have a look at my example cannot make it work with :focus snack.expo.io/@ninjamate/textinput

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
state = {
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    }

    onFocus() {
        this.setState({
            backgroundColor: 'green'
        })
      }

      onBlur() {
        this.setState({
          backgroundColor: '#ededed'
        })
      }

    <TextInput 
        onBlur={ () => this.onBlur() }
    onFocus={ () => this.onFocus() }
    style={{ height:60, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor }}  />
```

Comment: have a look at my example cannot make it work with :focus  https://snack.expo.io/@ninjamate/textinput

Comment: outline is not any property you are using. Thanks for voting up

Answer (score 0):

If your using react-jss you can specify event styling like focus and hover like this `&:hover &:focus`